# How can I get this double google search-bar away?

Tags: html, css

I need to create the google home page for a project using html and css. And the red marked box of code (in the second picture and in the code the bold and italian text), I have to involve into the code, but when I want to put it in, I get as a result this double search bar (first picture), which is also not in the size I want to have it. I put in the code box a part of my html code which you can see also in the second picture. Can someone help me there out?

PS I can't put the css code for a reason in the question so you can see it only in the picture I'm sorry.

[how the code looks in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCdcK.png)          [picture of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDBIk.png)

```
    <div class="content">
  <div class="search-wrapper">
    <a href="" class="search-logo">
      <img src="google copy.jpg">
    </a>
    <div class="search-bar">
        ***<form action="https://google.com/search">
          <input type="text" name="q">
          <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
          </form>***
      <div class="search-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </div>
      <input type="text">
      <div class="search-icon right">
        <i class="fa fa-microphone"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="search-buttons">
      <a href="">Google Search</a>
      <a href="">I'm Feeling Lucky</a>
    </div>
    <p class="search-info">
      This is a search bar. <a href="">Random Link</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does that `<input type="text">` do below the `search-icon` div and above `search-icon right` div? I suspect that is where your other input field is coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just added extra `<input>` tag. Check this code:

```html
        <div class="content">
            <div class="search-wrapper">
                <a href="" class="search-logo">
                    <img src="google copy.jpg">
                </a>
                <div class="search-bar">***
                    <form action="https://google.com/search">
                        <input type="text" name="q">
                        <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
                    </form>***
                    <div class="search-icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </div>
                    <!-- REMOVE THIS <input> -->
                    <div class="search-icon right">
                        <i class="fa fa-microphone"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="search-buttons">
                    <a href="">Google Search</a>
                    <a href="">I'm Feeling Lucky</a>
                </div>
                <p class="search-info">
                This is a search bar. <a href="">Random Link</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not apply your css, only the html, but if I remove the `input` field I mentioned in my comment, the second textbox goes away

```html
    <div class="content">
  <div class="search-wrapper">
    <a href="" class="search-logo">
      <img src="google copy.jpg">
    </a>
    <div class="search-bar">
        ***<form action="https://google.com/search">
          <input type="text" name="q">
          <input type="submit" value="Google Search">
          </form>***
      <div class="search-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </div>
      <!-- REMOVE THIS? <input type="text"> -->
      <div class="search-icon right">
        <i class="fa fa-microphone"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="search-buttons">
      <a href="">Google Search</a>
      <a href="">I'm Feeling Lucky</a>
    </div>
    <p class="search-info">
      This is a search bar. <a href="">Random Link</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```